# MySQL database backup and restore with Java GUI

Tags: java, mysql, netbeans, database-backups, database-restore

I found a java code for DB backup. This work properly

```
String sql1 = "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\MySQL\\MySQL Server 4.1\\bin\\mysqldump -uroot -    p123 exepro -r C:\\Users\\Dell\\Desktop\\Backup\\"+jLabel1.getText()+".sql";
        Runtime.getRuntime().exec(sql1);
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(rootPane, "Success");
```

and also a restore code from my teacher as fallows

```
String[] executeCmd = new String[]{"D:\\mysql",databaseName, "-u"+ username, "-p"+ password, "-e", "source D:/sqlbackup.sql"};
```

Problem is I have no idea how to implement this code to my application.Can you give an answers related to my backup code.

Comment: look at this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8470760/how-to-backup-and-restore-mysql-database-using-java?rq=1

Comment: In backup code exepro is my database I get the file name from a jlable

Comment: I also looked for that but he is using fedora 14 and I dont get his code

Answer (score -1):

you can use this simple code to restore your database

```
        try {
        String[] executeCmd = new String[]{"C:\\mysql", "svdb", "-u" + "username", "-p" + "password", "-e", "source d:\\HesabYar_1393-7-24.sql"};
        Process p=Runtime.getRuntime().exec(executeCmd);
        if (p.waitFor()!=-1) {
            System.err.println("Success !");
        }
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(RuntimeProject.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(RuntimeProject.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
```